# ¿como mandar datos a MYSQL a través de un modal dialog con bootstrap?

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal

Que tal, ojala alguien me pueda ayudar, llevo rato sin poder realizar esta acción, apenas estoy empezando y no se mucho.
Les platico, estoy trabajando con bootstrap y tengo una ventana modal que sale al seleccionar un boton llamado "Agregar"; el modal contiene dos cajas de texto, una "txt_trabajo" y la otra "txt_costo"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero hacer, es que al llenar los campos y hacer click en el boton GUARDAR, aparezca en automático en mi BD en mysql en la tabla llamada trabajos, que tiene 3 campos "Id_trabajo", "Nombre_Trabajo" y "Costo"

y que también aparezca en mi tabla, que tengo debajo de el boton "guardar", la cual muestra todos los datos que estan en mi tabla "trabajos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo del modal

```html
<!--Boton para agregar un nuvo trabajo a  la lista-->
<div id="btnAddUser" class="center addUser">
  <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <h3 class='text-right'>   
        <button id="goNuevoUser" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Agregar</button>
      </h3>
  </div>
</div>

<!--MODAL PARA AGREGAR UN NUEVO trabajo A LA BD Y A LA TABLA-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Trabajo</h4>
      </div>
      <!--Contenido del modal-->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control " type="text" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control " type="text" name="txt_costo" placeholder="Costo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Final del modal-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

como puedo hacer para mandar los datos a la BD y que aparezcan en la tabla?
que puedo hacer o usar?
me dijieron que atravez de ajax, pero no se como se usa
o como mas le puedo hacer? es que mi idea es que sea una lista de precios, la cual posteriormente se pueda modificar el costo o agregar un nuevo producto

gracias

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es meter un form dentro de la ventana modal.

Modal:

```html
<!-- Modal agregar-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregar" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Trabajo</h4>
   </div>
//En el action iria el código PHP donde haces el INSERT a BD
   <form id="formAdd" method="POST" action="agregar_trabajo.php">
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control " type="text" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo">
     </div>
     
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label> <input class="form-control " type="text" name="txt_costo" placeholder="Costo">
     </div>
     
 
     
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Agregar_trabajo.php

```html
//Recoges las variables mediante POST e insertas en tu tabla.
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Comment: gracias, ya lo intente pero sigue sin funcionar, mira te dejo mi código: